# #1604 mysql error when creating a foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I am creating a database for a DVD shop for a uni project and i am having some issues when creating a foreign key i am sure its something really stupid i am missing. So here is the problem i have so far created two tables and I'm now trying to create the third one that contains the primary key from the first two tables here is the SQL for the first two tables and the one I'm having the issue with. 
Thanks in  advance for any help you can give me

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORY (
CAT_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CATEGORY varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`CAT_ID`))

CREATE TABLE AGE_CERT (
AGE_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
DVD_AGE varchar(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`AGE_ID`))

CREATE TABLE DVD (
DVD_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
DVD_NAME varchar(30) NOT NULL,
DVD_COST varchar (4) NOT NULL,
AGE_ID INT NOT NULL,
CAT_ID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`DVD_ID`)
FOREIGN KEY (AGE_ID) references AGE_CERT (AGE_ID) 
FOREIGN KEY (CAT_ID) references CATEGORY (CAT_ID))
```

Comment: for some reason it has taken all the paragraphing didnt work on the post so where i have pressed enter for the creation of new lines its not worked

Comment: welcome to SO, anytime you post code, select it all and hit control+K to keep the formatting

Comment: The error message tells the exact location of the error. I can't understand why you decided that information is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot 2 commas between the keys

```
CREATE TABLE DVD 
(
  DVD_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DVD_NAME varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  DVD_COST varchar (4) NOT NULL,
  AGE_ID INT NOT NULL, 
  CAT_ID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DVD_ID`), /* forgot the comma here */
  FOREIGN KEY (AGE_ID) references AGE_CERT (AGE_ID), /* forgot the comma here */
  FOREIGN KEY (CAT_ID) references CATEGORY (CAT_ID)
)
```

Comment: use a comment to point out which ones..? (can be hard to spot if you're new..)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick response that seems to of worked and got me past the 1604 error. though i am now getting  #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Comment: ok so i droped the first two tables and ran the SQL as a all in one like in your link and it worked. there must of been a error or typo in one of the first two when i created them.

Comment: Thank you again for your help!! i have a funny feeling i may be asking for it again before the day is out... Sorry!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it solved your question (use the checkbox to the left of the answer).  It makes it easier for other users find answers that work.